# AWS CloudFormation how can I use conditions in the mapping block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I have the following mapping that I wanted to use condition statements in:

```yaml
Conditions:
  IsChinaSite:
    !Equals [!Ref SiteType, 'ChinaSite']

Mappings:
  Environment2Env:
    Develop:
      ENV: Dev
      ApiRegion: us-east-1  # There is no test CN data so we are going to keep using test US data in test envs
    Test:
      ENV: Qual
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    Staging:
      ENV: Test
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    Production:
      ENV: Prod
      FleetApiRegion: !If[IsChinaSite, ap-northeast-1, us-east-1]
```

As you can see I am trying to sigv4 sign to a different region depending on the value of an input param in the prod version of my site. However [after reading the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) it seems you cant use condition statements in the `Mappings` block of your template. How/where should I go about checking the `IsChinaSite` condition?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to just split out the regions into their own mapping under each env. Wound up with this:

```yaml
Mappings:
  Environment2Env:
    Develop:
      ENV: Dev
    Test:
      ENV: Qual
    Staging:
      ENV: Test
    USProduction:
      Env: Prod
    ChinaProduction:
      ENV: Prod

  Develop:
    ROW: us-east-1
    ChinaSite: us-east-1
  Test:
    ROW: us-east-1
    ChinaSite: us-east-1
  Staging:
    ROW: us-east-1
    ChinaSite: us-east-1
  Production:
    ROW: us-east-1
    ChinaSite: ap-northeast-1
```

This solution worked for me because thankfully I was only parameterizing with 2 dimensions (the max/min dimensions required to make a CloudFormation mapping) but that was kind of dumb luck. Had I been in a situation where I needed to deploy in multiple envs, with multiple types of sites, AND each type of site had some sort of sub-type, I would have been scr---d. I still think the right answer here is something that can support x^n number of dimensions so I don't think I am going to accept my own answer but I wanted to share my solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I image you can mix an If and FindInMap to get the result you want

```
Conditions:
  IsChinaSite:
    !Equals [!Ref SiteType, 'ChinaSite']


Mappings:
  Environment2Env:
    Develop:
      ENV: Dev
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    Test:
      ENV: Qual
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    Staging:
      ENV: Test
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    USProduction:
      Env: Prod
      ApiRegion: us-east-1
    ChinaProduction:
      ENV: Prod
      ApiRegion: ap-northeast-1

Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        !If
          - IsChainSite
          - !FindInMap [Environment2Env, ChinaProduction, ApiRegion]
          - !FindInMap [Environment2Env, USProduction, ApiRegion]
```

Comment: I thought of doing this too, but it requires I have an "env" and "CNenv" entry for every environment. If I start adding  European or African or Asian regions the entries are going to multiply. Was trying to avoid that.

Comment: In that case, it seems like the Parameter value `SiteType` essentially decides the region. So maybe this abstraction isn't adding value? Maybe just pass in the desired region instead. Or are you launching into the desired region each time? You could always just use `!Ref AWS::Region`

Comment: No yeah I would have used AWS::Region if that was the case. Sometimes the "China" site is deployed in a china region, but not always.